# Jquery .html() in Ajax Success doesnot work well because of dom update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

This script is asking a youtube video url. It sends url to ajax do filters and get data from ajax and set a youtube player with progress bar which can control youtube video. This part is responsible for this task.

```html
$('#youtubeUrl').on('input',function(e){
   urlm = $('#youtubeUrl').val();
        pageName =  "addYoutube";
         Data = {
            page: pageName,
                     url: urlm
                };
if(urlm.length > 40 )
{ 
          var ajaxResult = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: formUrl,
            data: Data,
            global: false,
      async:false,
            success: function (data) {
              if(data != "nope"){
               
               $(".ytInput").css("display", "none");
               $("#ytOutter").css("display" , "block");
      $("#ytResLink").css("display" , "block");       
  
  $("#ytOutter").html('<div class="ytDiv embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe width="640" height="480" allowtransparency="true"allowfullscreen id="player" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&autohide=2&rel=0&version=3&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><div class="nstSlider cubuk" data-range_min="0" data-cur_min="0"><div class="bar"></div><a  class="grp leftGrip"></a><a  class="grp rightGrip"></a></div></div>');
  

              }

                          },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
                                   }
              });
     

  




     


}//url>11 






});
```

In this current code above, It makes player work but nstSlider doesnot work well, it set though but I am not able to slide selectors and it is not controlling the video. I know the reason I think. Because when I check the console it doesnot give any error but when I check dom elements those are different.

And this Dom output is the one that the upper full code gives. In this case it doesnot update Dom elements and nstSlider doesnot work well.

```html
<div style="display: block;" id="ytOutter">
  <div class="ytDiv embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe width="640" height="480" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="" id="player" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?enablejsapi=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autohide=2&amp;rel=0&amp;version=3&amp;loop=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;controls=0&amp;autoplay=1"
    frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <div class="nstSlider cubuk" data-range_min="0" data-cur_min="0">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <a class="grp leftGrip"></a>
      <a class="grp rightGrip"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I have two options. The former, I can update VIDEOID in first case or the latter I can update Dom elements. Isnot it strange?

```html
$('#youtubeUrl').on('input',function(e){
   urlm = $('#youtubeUrl').val();
        pageName =  "addYoutube";
         Data = {
            page: pageName,
                     url: urlm
                };
if(urlm.length > 40 )
{ 
          var ajaxResult = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: formUrl,
            data: Data,
            global: false,
      async:false,
            success: function (data) {
              if(data != "nope"){
               
               $(".ytInput").css("display", "none");
               $("#ytOutter").css("display" , "block");
      $("#ytResLink").css("display" , "block");       

              }

                          },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
                                   }
              });
     

  




     


}//url>11 






});


  $("#ytOutter").html('<div class="ytDiv embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe width="640" height="480" allowtransparency="true"allowfullscreen id="player" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&autohide=2&rel=0&version=3&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><div class="nstSlider cubuk" data-range_min="0" data-cur_min="0"><div class="bar"></div><a  class="grp leftGrip"></a><a  class="grp rightGrip"></a></div></div>');
```

When I put this jquery part

```html
$("#ytOutter").html('<div class="ytDiv embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe width="640" height="480" allowtransparency="true"allowfullscreen id="player" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&autohide=2&rel=0&version=3&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><div class="nstSlider cubuk" data-range_min="0" data-cur_min="0"><div class="bar"></div><a  class="grp leftGrip"></a><a  class="grp rightGrip"></a></div></div>');
```

out of

> $('#youtubeUrl').on('input',function(e){ ... });

it works, but in this case yt player and progress bar are set and when I get data from ajax I cant update VIDEOID in player. But if I can update it, it will work. Working Dom output is following code:

```html
<div style="display: block;" id="ytOutter">
  <div class="ytDiv embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe width="640" height="480" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="" id="player" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID ?enablejsapi=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autohide=2&amp;rel=0&amp;version=3&amp;loop=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;controls=0&amp;autoplay=1"
    frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <div class="nstSlider cubuk" data-range_min="0" data-cur_min="0" data-range_max="385" data-cur_max="385">
      <div class="bar" style="left: 0px; width: 100px; background: green;"></div>
      <a class="grp leftGrip" tabindex="0" style="left: 0px;"></a>
      <a class="grp rightGrip" tabindex="0" style="left: 80px;"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you use data anywhere? if you don't why are you doing the ajax call? if you do, what are you getting back? you always want this video `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&autohide=2&rel=0&version=3&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0&autoplay=1"` or that's what you are changing?

Comment: when input string size over 40, i send the input value to php file via ajax and it returns data to this file. If there isnot an available video on youtube data returns "nope", if there is a video available on youtube, data returns VIDEOID.

Comment: in that case souldn't you do something like `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+data+'?enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&autoh‌​ide=2&rel=0&version=3&loop=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0&autoplay=1"`

Comment: in my code i am doing it as same as yours, the point when i add $("#ytOutter").html('<div class="ytDiv embed-responsive ...... ) including VIDEOID in $('#youtubeUrl').on('input',function(e){........} inside, DOM of nstSlider is not being updated and so player is working but that progress bar no working bcs of not updated dom element. When I add $("#ytOutter").html('<div class="ytDiv embed-responsive ...... ) out of .on method braces,player and bar works, but I cant update VIDEOID with data variable bcs data will be in another function. I tried to use window.variable, it didnot work neither.